# Grouping by months and by column with diferent values

Tags: mysql

I am having problems trying to create a query that allow me to group by months and by a column that has different values.

The following is a small representation of the table and columns I need to query.

Table name is requests and has two columns date and status. Status may have the values pending, attended, absent and canceled.

I want to get a query that looks like this

[image: Target]

Right now i am trying a subquery on status for each possible value. It works but is a very slow query. It takes arround 48s for 8000 rows.

```
SELECT
    MONTHNAME(date)
    (SELECT count(status) FROM requests WHERE status = "pending"),
    (SELECT count(status) FROM requests WHERE status = "attended"),
    (SELECT count(status) FROM requests WHERE status = "absent"),
    (SELECT count(status) FROM requests WHERE status = "canceled")
FROM request
GROUP BY 1;
```

Any recommendations on how to get the result efficiently? Thank you very much

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use case whene on status instead of several subselect

```
  select  
        MONTHNAME(date) 
      , sum( case when status = "pending" then 1 else 0 end) pending
      , sum( case when status = "attended" then 1 else 0 end) attended
      , sum( case when status = "absent" then 1 else 0 end) absent
      , sum( case when status = "canceled" then 1 else 0 end) canceled
  FROM request
  GROUP BY  MONTHNAME(date) ;
```

Comment: nice one...but can you please create another query for this using dynamic query

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal  your comment is not clear to me (seems not related  to the question)

Comment: i am saying that can you please edit your answer in form of dynamic query where input value of status is dynamic

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal  The use of case when in this case for not dinamic values for status .. .. and i think is not easy find a solution for dinamic query as yoy like in SQL .. could be using server side language for generate dinamically the query 
 .. eventually try post a new question properly described  .. could be someone else is able to find a solution